# Why do I get "vacationing is a required value" when it has a default value set in the model?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm simplifying this for my question, but, as an example, let's say I have a model with an entity named `Employee` and a Boolean attribute named `vacationing` which is non-optional but has a default value of `NO` set.

However, I'm seeing "vacationing is a required value" when attempting to save an update to an `Employee` entity. The code looks like this:

```
- (void)reinstateEmployee:(Employee*)employee context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {
    employee.vacationing = NO;

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `NO` is really just an alias for `0` which also represents `nil` and `NULL`.

Since it's perfectly valid to assign `nil` to an `NSNumber` property, the compiler does not complain and instead of setting `vacationing` to false, it unsets it, which is not valid when the attribute is required.

This is more obvious by replacing `NO` with `YES`, which will produce a compiler warning.

To fix the issue, replace `NO` with `@NO` or `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` to instead assign an `NSNumber` instance.